# Altium Designer: file could not be found and will be removed from the project

Tags: altium

I downloaded a repository (from GitHub) of Altium files, and I am wanting to modify the PCB before sending it for manufacturing. However, I get the error: file **could not be found and will be removed from the project** when opening it. However, I clearly see those files in the downloaded folders. How can I link the correct files to the project? **Thank you in advance for the help!**

Comment: one easy way is to let it remove them, and then just add them back manually by right clicking on the project file in altium and selecting "add existing item"

Comment: It's probably a problem with the relative path of files, Its not a big deal. Just do as @BeB00 said.

Comment: I tried what you both suggested, however, there are now holes in the schematic and pub where components should be. So although I was able to add those files back to the project, I do not know where to place them and they have been deleted from the schematic.